# Angular: Change component template using variables

Tags: angularjs, components, angular-components

my question is: Is possible to change the component template when the value of a variable changes in the parent controller?
Here there are two ways that I tried to follow:

```
var topBarTemplateWithButton = [
'<section id="filters">',
'<div class="pull-left">',
'<h1>{{$ctrl.step}}</h1>',
'<div class="pull-left pageActionContainer">',
'<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
'</div>',
'</div>',
'</section>'].join(' ')

var topBarTemplateWithoutButton = [
    '<section id="filters">',
    '<div class="pull-left">',
    '<h1>{{$ctrl.step}}</h1>',
    '</div>',
    '</section>'].join(' ')

myApp.component('topBar', {
    bindings: {
        step: '<'
    },
    template: this.templateToUse,
    transclude: true,
    controller: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.$onInit = function() {
            this.templateToUse = topBarTemplateWithButton;
        }

        me.$onChanges = function(changes) {
            if(changes.step.currentValue != "Projects") {
                this.templateToUse = this.topBarTemplateWithoutButton;
            }else {

                this.templateToUse = topBarTemplateWithButton;

            }
        }
    }
});
```

and

```
var topBarTemplateWithButton = [
    '<section id="filters">',
    '<div class="pull-left">',
    '<h1>{{$ctrl.step}}</h1>',
    '<div class="pull-left pageActionContainer">',
    '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
    '</div>',
    '</div>',
    '</section>'].join(' ')

var topBarTemplateWithoutButton = [
    '<section id="filters">',
    '<div class="pull-left">',
    '<h1>{{$ctrl.step}}</h1>',
    '</div>',
    '</section>'].join(' ')

myApp.component('topBar', {
    bindings: {
        step: '<'
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="$ctrl.templateToUse"/>,
    transclude: true,
    controller: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.$onInit = function() {
            this.templateToUse = topBarTemplateWithButton;
        }

        me.$onChanges = function(changes) {
            if(changes.step.currentValue != "Projects") {;
                this.templateToUse = this.topBarTemplateWithoutButton;
            }else {
                this.templateToUse = topBarTemplateWithButton;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Both these two examples don't work. So it's possible to change the template of this component when the value of `step` changes? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You would need to have the parent controller pass the value into the component, and I would just use template directives like `ng-if`, `ng-show`, `ng-hide`, etc. to alter the component

Comment: The `ng-if` directive is the best example on how to do it. To change HTML on the fly, watchers need to be de-registered, scope need to be destroyed, new HTML needs a new scope, and directives need to be compiled and linked. To see how it is done: [ng-if source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js). Or just use the [ng-if directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

Comment: @theaccordance  thank you for your answer

Comment: @georgeawg thank you too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `Template` field can be a function that returns a template, and it takes `attrs` as an injectable. Here's an example that might accomplish what you're looking for.

```
template: function(attrs) {
    "ngInject";
    // check for custom attribute and return different template if it's there
},
```

Important point, however, is that these are *uncompiled* attributes at this point, because the template hasn't been compiled. It can't be compiled, in fact, until the template is determined. So them attribute you inspect can only be a string literal..

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not the best practice to use two different templates for one component. The main rule is to use one controller with one view. So from this perspective it's better to achieve this behavior is to use `ng-switch` or `ng-if` inside component template or even to make two different `dumb` components - `topBarWithButton` and `topBarWithoutButton`. In these both cases you interact with component via bindings. I think this is a bit hacky to use `attrs` instead of using `bindings`. Components is not directves so you have to think in terms of components when you build component-based app. I think there are a lot of reasons why you shouldn't use attrs:

1. You can't change template after it was compiled.
2. You can't change state of your component.
3. You keep state in html template.
4. It's not easy to test this approach.